# GCC compiler output for specific functions

Tags: c++, debugging, gcc, optimization, vectorization

I am trying to use GCC auto vectorization to perform some optimizations and I would like to see diagnostic informations whether optimizations have been done or what hinders their performance. I could use -fopt-info-*option* for this, but applying this flag to whole build or file, generates tons of informations I have to dig through. So I am looking for a way to limit this output for specific functions. Could it be done? My piece of code looks like this:

```
template<unsigned InOutVectorAligment = 1, typename InOutVectorType>
inline void swapValuesInVector(InOutVectorType* __restrict__ inout,
        InOutVectorType oldValue, InOutVectorType newValue,
        int vectorLength) {
    inout = (InOutVectorType*)__builtin_assume_aligned(inout, InOutVectorAligment);
    for(int i = 0; i < vectorLength; ++i) {
        inout[i] = inout[i] == oldValue ? newValue : inout[i];
    }
}

//static inline void changeZerosToOnes(unsigned char *array, int arrayLength)
//__attribute__ ((optimize("-O3"), optimize("-ffast-math"), __target__("avx")));

#pragma GCC optimize ("-O3", "-ffast-math")
#pragma GCC target ("avx")
static inline void changeZerosToOnes(unsigned char *array, int arrayLength);

void changeZerosToOnes(unsigned char *array, int arrayLength) {
    constexpr unsigned arrayAligment = 32;
    assert(((unsigned long)array % arrayAligment) == 0);
    swapValuesInVector<arrayAligment>(array, (unsigned char)0, (unsigned char)1, arrayLength);
}
```

I want to see diagnostics for function changeZerosToOnes.